# Async with redirecting routes in Express

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I am building a web application using Node.js/Express. I have a route whose only function is to redirect to another route. This other route is async. I was wondering if the original route also needs to be async. For example,

```
router.get('/routeA', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/routeB');
});

router.get('/routeB', async (req, res) => {
  // Async code
});
```

In this case, does the routeA middleware function need to be made async:

```
router.get('/routeA', async (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/routeB');
});
```

I'm a newbie...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if the original route also needs to be async

No, it does not.  The two routes actually have nothing to do with one another and are completely separate.

The fact that you're asking this question suggests that you aren't really sure what happens with a redirect so I will explain that and then it will be clear why the answer to your question is what it is.

Here's the sequence of events that happens when a client requests the route `/routeA`:

1. Client requests `/routeA`.
2. Server receives that request and matches it to your specific route handler.
3. That route handler calls `res.redirect('/routeB');`
4. That function call sends a 302 http response back to the client with the `Location:` header set to `/routeB`.
5. Your server is now completely done with that first request.
6. The client receives the 302 response back from the original request, sees that it's a 302 response and gets the `Location` header from that response.
7. If the client wants to follow that redirect, then it issues a new request to that same host for `/routeB`.
8. Your server receives a new request for `/routeB`.
9. Your server runs its asynchronous code and then (presumably) sends a response back to the client.
10. Client receives that response and processes it.

So, the first thing you should see here is that from the server's point of view, the second request for `/routeB` has nothing at all to do with the first request.  That first request to `/routeA` is completely done and over.  Then, some time later the second request for `/routeB` arrives.  That might or might not be in response to a redirect and the server doesn't really care.  Other clients might just request `/routeB` directly.

So, it is NOT like routeA is calling routeB.  This is not like regular function calls where one async function calls another.

---

Here's a bit of an analogy.  You are out of the country travelling when your friend Bob calls you from home.  Because you're travelling, it's a long distance call for Bob and he gets charged a fee for that call.  But, what Bob is calling you about is he wants you to give him Jack's phone number (Jack is another friend from home).  You happily supply him with Jack's phone number and then your call is finished.

Now, using that phone number you gave him, Bob calls Jack.  Since both Bob and Jack are in the same city, it's not a local call and no service fee is charged for that call.

As in the redirect, once you've given Jack's phone number to Bob and finished your call, your call is completely done.  What Bob does after that with that phone number (kind of like a redirect) has nothing to do with you and nothing to do with your original call.  Bob, then makes an entirely new call to reach Jack.

The phone numbers in this analogy are like request paths.  The server is like the local phone company.  Each of Bob's calls are completely separate and have nothing to do with one another just like the two client requests to your server are completely separate.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: No.

`res.redirect` redirects to the URL derived from the specified path, with specified status, a positive integer that corresponds to an HTTP status code. If not specified, status defaults to “302 “Found”. please check the link for more [info](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect).